# Use execution trace on-chip buffer (ETB) on STM32H7

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, trace

I need to output the on-chip buffer (ETB) execution trace in some particular cases. I'm talking about an operational functionality, not about ETM trace during debugging phase.

I've read *Arm® CoreSight™ ETM-M7 Technical Reference Manual* but there is almost no detail about using this ETB feature.

There is also [this link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0314h/Chdiddei.html) on ARM Information center, but I found it particularly unclear.

How can I use ETB ?

EDIT: I clarified a little bit the situation thanks to a presentation from STMicro. It states that "*The ETF can be used as a trace buffer for storing traces onchip. The trace can be read by software, or by the debugger,
or flushed via the trace port. If configured as a circular buffer,
the trace will be stored continuously, so the most recent trace
will overwrite the oldest. Alternatively, the FIFO full flag can
be used to stop a trace when the buffer is full, and hence
capture a trace at a particular point in time*."  So what I need to access is not the ETB but the ETF, which is done through a register (the FIFO is apparently not memory mapped ?)

Comment: ETB and ETF are different components, ETB being an older (but still relevant) component. The ETF is more of an in-line buffer which can be configured to drain (a) nowhere, (b) to a traceport, (c) to system memory. The first of these might be referred to as ETF in ETB mode.

Comment: Yes you're right, the Trace Memory Controller ref manual describes ETF and ETB as different configurations of the Trace Memory Controler, decided at chip design. "Embedded Trace FIFO (ETF)
Enables trace to be stored in a dedicated SRAM, used either as a Circular
Buffer or as a FIFO. The functionality of this configuration is a superset
of the functionality of the ETB configuration"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the CoreSight Architecture and ETM trace *are* designed to enable this sort of crash analysis, particularly in realtime systems where crashes can be difficult to reproduce and you may not able to have the target device hooked up to an external debug capture device all the time. ETM trace can be completely non-intrusive (except for the additional power consumption cost of having the logic active).

The architecture is quite generic, although each implementation will make different trade-offs about what is implemented. This unfortunately means that the documentation is quite spread-out. You might find this [technical overview](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.epm039795/coresight_technical_introduction_EPM_039795.pdf) is useful for context (but not detail).

To achieve the crash analysis, you need to cover the following steps:

1. Configure ETF in circular buffer mode
2. Configure ETM to trace everything, with fairly frequent synchronisation
3. Disable the ETM after a crash (so the buffer is not overwritten)
4. Extract the trace from the crash (to SD card, for example)
5. Unpack any wrapping protocol added by the ETF
6. Decompress the trace (presumably offline)

With a circular buffer, trace decompression can only start from a synchronisation point. The ETMv4 protocol uses variable length packets, and rarely traces a full PC address value. You probably want 4 synchronisation points in the buffer, then only the first 25% is lost.

Trace decompression relies on having the code image which was running - this shouldn't be too much of a problem in this use case.

If you can't buffer far back enough after a crash, it is possible to use the filtering logic in the ETM to exclude any code you know is not interesting. Depending on the nature of any crash, you might want timing information. You can set this with a threshold to get a tick in the trace every 100 cycles or so - trace accuracy for cost, but it might be a great clue.

For programming the ETM, you want the [ETMv4 architecture](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ihi0064/latest) (it uses DWT comparators as 'processor comparator inputs' if you need filtering) and for the ETF I think it will be this [technical reference manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0461b/DDI0461B_tmc_r0p1_trm.pdf). Check **part_number** in the Peripheral ID registers to make sure you have the right programmer's model.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use the ETB with a hardware debugger that supports ETB such as [Segger J-Trace](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-trace/technology/streaming-trace/) or [Keil uLinkPro](http://www2.keil.com/mdk5/ulink/ulinkpro) for example.  It is something normally for the tool vendor to worry about and not directly usable within your application.

The necessary trace pins (TRACED0 to TRACED3 and TRACECLK) need to be available on your debug header, and not multiplexed to some other function by your application.

The STM32H7 Reference manuals contain a whole section on the "Trace and debug subsystem" (you have not specified the exact part, so you'll have to find it yourself).  But in the RM0399 for STM32H745/755 and STM32H747/757 I am looking at it occupies over 100 pages of the manual.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about ETB specifcally ? I agree the ETM is supported by tools like Segger, UlinkPro or Lauterbach but it is not what I am talking about. I'm really interested in the ETB, ie. accessing the execution trace buffer in operation (through a protocol to be defined, but definitely not SWD or JTAG). And I'm well aware of the STM32H7 Reference Manual but  these 100 pages are pretty unclear to say the least, especially for everything that concern ETM.

Comment: Did you look at the complete documentation hierarchy for ETB http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0242b/index.html? Especially the "intended audience"; the ETB is clearly _an_ implementation of instruction buffer for the ETM.  There is more than one implementation (again look at the documentation hierarchy).  It is really not clear either what you expect it wish to achieve.

Comment: I try to clarify: I want to get an execution trace but not for debugging purpose during validation or development steps. Instead I need to get this trace in operational mode, so without any debugging tool connected. For example if the formware detects a critical issue (through watchdog or other means) it will output the previous execution trace so that an external tool can analyse it later on. My team understood we could implement it through ETB. In the documentation it is clear that ETM trace can be accessed by two means: either through TPIU (which is used by debugging tools) or through ETB,

Comment: About the documentation I agree that is seems more intended to HW developers, but on this other hand it states : ""This document has been written for experienced hardware and software engineers who want to design or obtain trace information from chips that use ARM cores with the ETM facility.""