# Cannot write TMC/ETF registers on STM32H753

Tags: arm, stm32, trace

This question is the follow-up of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220113/use-execution-trace-on-chip-buffer-etb-on-stm32h7/58225065?noredirect=1#comment102860431_58225065).

I try to configure the ETF in circular mode in order to be able to read the execution trace through the embedded software in case of critical error, on a STM32H753.

I am following the algorithm described in ARM's Trace Memory Controller reference manual (section 2.2.2)

But I cannot write the ETF registers: I unlocked the ETF macrocell by writing the magic number `0xC5ACCE55`to register `ETF_LAR` but when I read thez registers they are all 0 (through debugger or printf) and when I write them they remain at 0.

Any advice on how to write ETF registers ?

Comment: First, confirm that you can read non-zero values from the ID registers (and others in that peripheral). It is possible that you need to enable something else first before the trace components are active (general power saving since these are never used in typical applications)

Comment: That's what I've written, all registers are read to 0.This is exactly what i'm asking: there is indeed something to enable but what ?

Comment: IT wasn't clear if just `ETF_LAR`, or all ETF registers. The ID registers don't need 'unlocked' to read 0xB105F00D. The detail is ST specific, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. I double checked and I confirm that the ETF ID registers are also read to 0 (from debugger).

Comment: Worth to add: the ID registers for ETM are indeed read correctly without unlocking ETM_LAR

Comment: ETF might well be in a different (debug) power domain which needs to be enabled. It looks like ETM is in the core power domain, so it will be on automatically.

Comment: Good point. Indeed the ref manual says that the clock of ETF : "CK_DBG_D1 clocks the trace components in the D1 power domain: System ROM table 2,
CoreSight trace funnel, ETF, system CTI and TPIU. It is a gated version of the D1 domain
system clock (CK_HCLK_D1)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a mistake in the STM32H7 doc:

[image]

and few pages later:
[image]

My understanding is that the second image is wrong.

Also I had to use the "Component base address (system bus)" and not the "component base address (debugger)". This notion of double address is pretty confusing as for example for ETM there is only one address.

Anyway using `0x5C014000`as base address, I can read/write the registers

Comment: The ETM has a special private port from the core local interconnect, all the components above have a sort of loop-back through the DAP (being extra over a minimal possible solution).

Answer (score 0):

When accesses are made using the DAP (SWD or JTAG), the debug subsystem should be powered up as part of the handshake with the tools. In a self-hosted debug mode, then device specific control of clocks/power is usually necessary.

For STM32H7, parts:

The ETM is in the same clock/power domain as the core, so it will normally be visible.

> CK_DBG_D1 clocks the trace components in the D1 power domain: System
>   ROM table 2, CoreSight trace funnel, ETF, system CTI and TPIU. It is a
>   gated version of the D1 domain system clock (CK_HCLK_D1).

Self hosted debug clock and power control uses a dedicated set of registers.

> All the debug clocks (except DAPCLK) can be enabled and disabled by
>   register bits in the DBGMCU.

Comment: I checked DBGMCU register and CK_DBG_D1 is enabled.